# Python string splitt error

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

I get the following error in my Python 3 code, it says:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I want to get the first element of the list. 
The code looks like this :

```
session = "TEST = 123;"
session = session.encode("utf-8")
print(type(session))
session = session.split(",")[0]
```

I tried to encode the session to UTF-8 and tried to cast to a bytes - with the same error as a result.

Comment: your current code does not behave the way you describe. Please edit your question and provide a minimal example that demonstrates your behavior.

Comment: That code works fine. Please edit it into a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `byte` methods on a bytes object, the arguments you provide must also be `bytes`. In short, you'll need to change the argument to `split` to be of `bytes` type:

```
session = session.split(b",")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the encoded bytes on a delimiter of encoded bytes.

```
session = session.split(b",")[0]
                        ^
```